# Pseudo inverse does not satisfy original problem although matrix has sufficient rank

Tags: matrix-equations, least-squares

I have a $4(\text{rows}) \times 5(\text{col})$ matrix. Lets call it $A$. I want to solve $AX = b$ where $b$ is $4 \times 1$ vector. Verified with `Matlab` that `rank(A)` is $4$. So all $b$ must be in the range space of the operator $A$ and not just in a 'least-squared' sense.

However if i use `X = pinv(A)*b`, i get a 'solution' that does not satisfy $AX = b$.

What am i missing?

Comment: You should also verify $\text{rank}(A|b)$ (the rank of $A$ with the 6th column $b$). If $\text{rank}(A|b) \neq \text{rank}(A)$ then $AX=b$ has no solutions and `X = pinv(A)*b` gives you approximate solution (in a 'least-squared' sense). Only if $\text{rank}(A|b) = \text{rank}(A)$ you can claim that $b$ is in the range space of the operator $A$.

Comment: Thanks. I think i found the bug. It was part of a Matlab program where i was later constraining all elements of X to be positive. This was why it didn't satisfy the original equation.